# How would you use TypeScript to improve the type-ahead and type checking for JQueryUI function calls

Tags: typescript

When working with a jQuery UI widget, you often end up with something that follows this pattern:

$("#someId").someWidget("option", "someOption", value);

Is there a good way to model this interaction to get some useful type checking out of TypeScript? Technically you probably have the method defined like this:

someWidget(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string, optionValue: any): JQuery;

(Modeled after the provided jQuery UI type definitions)

So option value is basically "any" no matter the option name. Is there a way to overload the type definition further and maybe do some pattern matching on optionName? Or are there any plans for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to dig into the jQuery UI example,

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Samples/#Warship

which covers how to extend the jQuery interface type with additional methods.

The jQuery type is an interface type and interface types are open in TypeScript, meaning that later compilation units can add members to the type. Your example would be written like,

```
interface JQuery {
    someWidget(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string, optionValue: any): JQuery
}
```

As for overloading, methods can be overloaded on type but not value. Overloading on values would make a good suggestion on the CodePlex site.

Comment: chuck, that doesn't really answer the question. As you see in my question above, I have that exact line, but I'm asking a further question about it. Each option name really as a type ascribed to it in a jQuery UI Widget, it would be nice if there were some way to pattern match on optionName's value and enforce a type on optionValue accordingly.

Comment: Are you asserting that what I am currently asking for is not possible and represents a suggestion? In which case, I guess its an answer ;-)

Comment: The functionality I'm asking about isn't super important when designing types from scratch, but when trying to make it more pleasant or less error prone to use existing libraries, it would be a pretty useful thing.

Comment: From what I determined you had two questions, first how do you extend jQuery's type in TypeScript which is the first part of my answer. The second, overloading on the value of optionName, is not part of TypeScript and would make a good suggestion.